# The comments are not for extended dicussion

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments

In questions such as [Does C++11, 14, 17 or 20 introduce a standard constant for pi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778240/does-c11-14-17-or-20-introduce-a-standard-constant-for-pi), a set of comments have been removed and replaced with "Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat".

If the comments are not for extended discussion, what are they there for? Is "comments" a valid name? It has always been my assumption on any system with user generated content, that the comments one and only purpose, is extended discussion.

Would "comments" not be better named something else such as "notes" or another name that does not suggest that discussing the question/answer at length is a valid use of the system?

Comment: Hmm, I had a highly upvoted comment there, heck of a coincidence.  But good call from the mod, that comment trail devolved rather badly.

Comment: I' have not opened the link but, I have to say, who would want their screen filled up with a discussion about a 'standard constant for pi' in any language?  If there is no pi, can it not be typed in?  Has the value of pi started to change between languages/versions?  Is the approach of of the death-planet Nibiru begun to change mathematical constants?  What about physical constants?  Do i need to check the speed of light in a vacuum again?   Why do such questions exist at all?  Is it just me?  Am I going mad?

Comment: "Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.". In the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Of course it is not for discussion.

Answer (score 9):

The primary purpose of comments is to request clarification on some point in a question/answer. Sometimes, the request for clarification itself needs to be clarified, so comments can lead to discussion.

However, once that discussion has reached some form of resolution, it generally is no longer important and can be expunged. Similarly, if the discussion stops being a productive request for clarification and turns into something else, then it is not serving a useful purpose and likewise can be expunged.

Answer (score 5):

It's tough to describe anything that isn't actually *answering* the question as anything else besides commentating.  In that vein, when commentators commentate, we refer to that as "comments".

Now comments on Stack Exchange are a strange beast.  They're never going to be held on an equal platform as answers are, and this is why they're ripe for deletion.  However, they serve these useful functions:

- **Asking for clarification of the OP's problem**

Any comment not doing any of the above is eligible to be removed at any time, without notice.  Even the ones that *do* may be removed since the noise or chatter may have been transferred into something more long-lived, like a question or an answer.